# Android won't recognize java files

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio

[image: None of my files are showing up in Android Studio]

Recently, I've tried to check out someone else's branch of this project on Github. However, this caused a lot of problems. Mainly that there are no files listed in the Android version of the directory and when I try to run anything there is an error that says "Error: Module not specified." How do I fix this?

Comment: its probably missing some config files. you need to import it in a way that allows studio to add them for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Also, my version works perfectly but this slightly different version changed .idea/modules.xml and app/app.iml which causes a lot of the crashes.

Comment: Yeah youll probably have to erase any imi files go through the android studio wizard to import a project or have the other person who is pushing to the repository remove their .ignore file and just upload everything and then you should get your build working.